# Error: Conversion from 'double' to non-scalar type 'Player' requested in function 'int main()';

Tags: c++, types, double

I'm not sure why I am getting an error here as I have very similar code in another program that runs just fine. This is my first time posting to this forum and so I'm not sure what to include but here is the code where I receive the error.

```
int AddPlayers(vector<Player>& players)
{
    string name;
    double wins;
    double losses;
    double draws;
    int x = 0;
    Player findPlayer("null", 0, 0, 0);
    cout << "Name of player you would like to add?" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    for (x = 0; x < players.size(); x++ )
    {
        findPlayer = players[x];
        findPlayer.getName();
        x++;
        if (name == findPlayer.getName())
        {
            cout << "That player is already in the tournament." << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        Player newPlayer = (name, wins, losses, draws);
        players.push_back(newPlayer);
    } 
}
```

Comment: The compiler tells you exactly what line the error occurs on.

Comment: +1 just to counter a previous downvote (a bit harsh to downvote a newcomer, even if his question obviously lacks research effort).

Comment: @Walter -1, disagree.

Comment: @Walter I disagree too. "even if his question obviously lacks research effort" - this is not an excuse. This **never can be an excuse.**

Comment: Also, [all the typo questions should be closed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions)

Answer (score 3):

```
Player newPlayer = (name, wins, losses, draws);
```

This is the wrong syntax. You're witnessing the comma operator in action, which is actually initializing `newPlayer` with the value of `draws`. Since `draws` is a `double`, the initialization gives you that error.

It appears you want:

```
Player newPlayer(name, wins, losses, draws);
```

Comment: Thanks.. wow such a simple mistake. I didnt realize I put that equal sign there. :O THANKS!

Comment: @chris if you think an answer was helpful, accept it!

Answer (score 1):

```
Player newPlayer = (name, wins, losses, draws);
```

After getting rid of the parentheses, you are left with

```
Player newPlayer = name, wins, losses, draws;
```

Now this is the comma operator: it evaluates its operands and returns the last one, which is `draw` in this case. `draw` is a `double`, and apparently there's no constructor for `Player` which takes a `double`, hence the error. Anyway, you want to construct an object out of the four variables:

```
Player newPlayer(name, wins, losses, draws);
```

Answer (score 1):

This instruction:

```
Player newPlayer = (name, wins, losses, draws);
```

Tries to copy-initialize a `Player` object from the expression `(name, wins, losses, draws)`. Due to the semantics of the comma operator, the value of the first three sub-expressions is discarded, and only the last sub-expression determines the value (and the type) of the expression.

Therefore, the expression:

```
(name, wins, losses, draws)
```

Is equivalent to the expression:

```
 (draws)
```

Since `draws` has type `double`, this is effectively an attempt to copy-initialize an object of type `Player` with a `double`. Since `Player` apparently does not have a constructor taking a `double`, the compiler generates an error.

You most likely did not want to write an expression there, but rather an argument list for `Player`'s constrctor:

```
 Player newPlayer(name, wins, losses, draws);
```